# Signing with Safe using WalletConnect

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm working on an EIP1271 implementation but have issues with Safe wallet on iOS after connecting to it using WalletConnect (using v2 documentation). The connection establishes successfully, but none of the functionality I need works; attempting to sign once connected throws "Method not found" or similar errors, and sending transactions throws "can't send transactions without a signer". I don't experience this problem using another SC wallet like Argent. Wonder what could be going wrong, or if anyone has done this successfully using Safe?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of WalletConnect in the iOS Safe{Wallet} only supports the `eth_sendTransaction` method.
Signing is not possible at the moment. It could be implemented via EIP-1271 offline signature collection. Or in case of 1/1 Safe by using the owner key, if imported. But neither is implemented in the iOS client.

Comment: So there's no practical way to do this, if I'm understanding correctly? What is meant by "offline signature collection"?